# Issues with Forms in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework-routing

```
I am getting the following error :
 Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_Employee' not found in /var/www/Employee/application/controllers/EmployeeController.php on line 31
```

I have created a separate folder for the forms in applications and placed the form Employee.php in the folder of Employee which is inside Forms . The routing in the application.ini is shown below : 
              resources.router.routes.employee.route = /employee

```
      resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.module = default           

  resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.controller = Employee

  resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.action = new  
   resources.router.routes.employee.route = /employee

resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.module = default           

resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.controller = Employee

resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.action = edit
resources.router.routes.employee.route = /employee

resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.module = default           

resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.controller = Employee

 resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.action = index
```

Please specify if any additional information required /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                                                                                                                                                P.S : I have tried to solve this error in a thousand ways by changing the folders and routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable forms simply and to correctly configure the resource, use the Zend_Tool cli.

At your command line or if your ide is compable (Netbeans is) enter the command:

```
zf enable form
```

this will create the correct directory for application level and Application namespaced forms.

When using application level forms the class name will be prefixed with `Application_Form_` and the file will exist at

```
/application
    /forms
        /Myform.php
```

If you need forms in a module simply alter the command to reflect the module name:

```
zf enable form -m admin
```

almost all commands in Zend_Tool cli can use the **-m** switch to specify a module name.

ZF1 has a number of predefine resources that have their own namespaces the class `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` has a complete list of the default namespaces along with the default path for each.

This answer assumes your application setup is reasonably close to a default ZF1 configuration.

**P.S.** I noticed that all of your routes have the same name 'employee'. If you want each of these routes to actually work, they need different names. The individual urls should work but the 'named' routes won't. Only the last route in the stack will work.

for example:

```
//4 lines equals one route
resources.router.routes.employee.route = /employee
resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.module = default           
resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.controller = Employee
resources.router.routes.employee.defaults.action = index


//this route might work better as
resources.router.routes.editEmployee.route = /employee/edit
resources.router.routes.editEmployee.defaults.module = default           
resources.router.routes.editEmployee.defaults.controller = Employee
resources.router.routes.editEmployee.defaults.action = edit
```

each 'named' route should have a unique name and a unique url.

Comment: I am still getting the same error , should i change the names any where else also ? and is the error related to placement of the file ?

Comment: ,I am getting the following error , when i am trying to display the fields though the details are being stored in the data base 
'Notice: Undefined variable: entryMessage in /var/www/Employee/application/models/EmployeeMapper.php on line 34 Fatal error: Call to a member function setEmployeeId() on a non-object in /var/www/Employee/application/models/EmployeeMapper.php on line 34 '

Comment: Start a new question and post your mapper code. This has nothing to do with your forms unless you just miss named an element.

Comment: ,I have posted the question , please check it :)

Answer (score -1):

You should not name your form class **Application_Form_Employee**.

It should be named **Form_Employee**. You should never prepend your class with **Application** in Zend.

For example, a model located inside application/Models/Test.php should be named Model_Test and *not* Application_Model_Test. Same for forms, services...

Comment: The same error is occuring eventhough if i change the name :(

Comment: @RockyFord , You are my saviour , please give me a solution

Comment: Current configuration standard uses the 'Application_' namespace. This is of course changeable in the application.ini

Comment: To confuse the issue, this namespace does not apply to controllers at the application level and only at the application level.